# How to get user's current location without asking for permission?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, core-location

can any one tell me how can i get the current location-latitude/longitude info of the user without asking his permission? Like getting user's location automatically?
Thanks in Advance.
Shreya

Comment: Cant you get the users ip? You could get some kind of location with that

Answer (score 8):

From apple's documentation

> Important: In addition to hardware not being available, the user has
>   the option of denying an application’s access to location service
>   data. During its initial uses by an application, the Core Location
>   framework prompts the user to confirm that using the location service
>   is acceptable. If the user denies the request, the CLLocationManager
>   object reports an appropriate error to its delegate during future
>   requests. You can also check the application’s explicit authorization
>   status using the authorizationStatus method.

So apple wont allow to use CoreLocation framework without user's permission. I don't thing there is no other way without using CoreLocation framework, atleast with public API..

Comment: Hi. Thanks for reply. But is there any other framework that does the functionality that i want or it will strictly be rejected by apple? Thanks in advance.

Comment: AFAIK user will be alerted if you use CoreLocation framework, and you don't have any control over that alert. Now without using Core Location, there is no public API's. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4334607/iphone-location-without-using-corelocation-framework) thread. And using private API's, I don't know any private API's are there..And if any one present, by using it, you run the risk of rejection. I wouldn't recommend it..

Comment: not to mention it strikes me as ethically dicey at best to grab a user's location without their permission.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't recommend trying to get around Apple's TOS regarding getting user's permission to enable CoreLocation for an app.  It seems like a sure fire way to get your app rejected.  Apple may be [sensitive about this kind of stuff](http://arstechnica.com/apple/news/2011/04/how-apple-tracks-your-location-without-your-consent-and-why-it-matters.ars).

[Here's a related question I found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2690255/iphone-sdk-do-i-need-to-ask-user-for-permissions-to-use-gps).

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply.. i want to know that if we use CLLocationManager in the begining of my app then will it be called every time user opens the app? or it will use the already stored location coordinates? Thanks in advance.

Comment: As far as I remember, once the user gives permission once, it's granted for all subsequent uses of the app.  If the user denies **twice**, then it's denied for all subsequent uses of the app.